# need jquery/backbone Framework for form based editing of data

Tags: jquery, json, backbone.js

I am finding SlickGrid https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid very useful for viewing and editing tabular data. Is there anything similar that works for form based data? I would like to knock out some scaffolding which edits  data delivered from rest services, and I dont want to re-invent the wheel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (creatively named) [backbone-forms](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms) project seems to fit the bill pretty well. I have no personal experience with it, but it seems promising based on the documentation.